# Title: Let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be matrices with all entries integers. If $\det(A) = 0$, must $\det(A + 4B)$ be even?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've tried considering small cases where the determinant should be easy to compute, such as making A diagonal sans a single diagonal entry, but this fails as the product of the diagonals would then be either 0 or a multiple of 4. This leads me to think it's true, but I haven't be able to go any further. I've tried induction, but I don't know what to induct on. I've tried doing it on n, the dimension of the matrix, but I end up with expressions that I don't completely know how to work with.

Comment: Yes. $\text{det}(A+4B)$ is always even.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider everything modulo $2$. In particular, because the determinant of a matrix is a polynomial in its entries, two matrices that have all entries equivalent modulo $2$ have determinants that are equivalent modulo $2$. Can you see how this helps?